# Extract a number with a letter

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to extract a number and add them in a range of cells if they are attached to a certain letter.

Ex: Cell B1=5C, Cell C1=3C, Cell D1=2B  Looking to extract and add all cells with the letter C. In this case my total should be 8. Also, if the Cell only contains a C it should equal 8. If the last part isn't easily easily done, I can always make it 8C.

Comment: Don't forget to mark as the answer if it solved the problem for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does exactly what you asked, C alone is 8 and adds up only the C numbers. Per your example it only checks B1:D1 for C.

```
=arrayformula(sum(iferror(if(SEARCH("C",B1:D1),if(len(B1:D1)=1,8,VALUE(substitute(upper(B1:D1),"C",""))),0),0)))
```

Comment: This work perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to add other letters to look for? For example, if I want to add anything with a letter C,P and F? Example: Cell B1=3C, Cell C1=6P, Cell D1=5F, Cell E1=4S; the whole thing should total 14.

Comment: @JoelMunoz what do these letters mean, maybe you should ask a new question about this, because your problem can be simplified or perhaps even more complicated than you think.

Comment: I'm trying to make a sick call sheet. For example C = Comp time, P = Personal Day, F = Family Reason. All these should be deducted out of sick leave with is (S) but I need to track them individually because each staff member is only allowed so many of each day.

Comment: @JoelMunoz What do the numbers mean? maybe it makes sense to do this in separate columns if it gets too complicated.